# TQ2-L2-5V latching relay

Tags: relay

I'm using a 2 coil latching relay named TQ2-L2-5V. I came to know that, 2 coil latching relays have two modes 1.SET and 2.RESET.

[image]

I want know, what happens in SET and RESET modes, in my case, in SET mode, the contact is not connecting to any of the pins in the relay. But in the reset mode it is coming to default state.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh4UZB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you show us how you wired it? There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: There is no 2 coil latching relay in the library

Comment: Use a single coil relay and an inductor for the second coil.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEl4SG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Wiring showing terminal numbers.*

Numbering should be as shown in Figure 1. You should see the indicator change state between set and reset.